# genfromtxt different datatypes

Tags: python, numpy, import, genfromtxt

I am trying to import data from a text file with varying number of columns.  I know that the first column will always be an int and subsequent cols will be floats in all files.  How can I specify this explicitly using dtypes?

```
dtypes=[int,float,float,float...] #this number will change depending on the number of columns in the file

data=np.genfromtxt(file,dtype=dtypes,delimiter='\t',skip_header=11) #read in 
the data
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the first few lines of you input file and the error message you receive?

Comment: Would `dtype=None` work for you?  Or leave dtype the default float and get a 2d array instead of a structured one.

Comment: I want a 2D array as later on I want to slice the data and alter certain columns.  I can leave it as a float, but I am writing new files and want to minimize the file size as much as possible by reducing numbers to int where possible.

Comment: The first row looks like this:  
1 0.00000 -26.28813 -48.48795 -542.29841 ....
I dont get an error if I manually type all the column data types, but in some cases I have more or less of the float type columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first read everything as `floats` and convert the array into a `structured array` after you know how many columns you have:

```
##input.txt:
##    1 1.4 5e23
##    2 2.3 5e-12
##    3 5.7 -1.3e-2

import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('input.txt')
print(data)
print('-'*50)

colw = data.shape[1]

dtypes = [('col0', int)]+[('col{}'.format(i+1),float) for i in range(colw-1)]
print(dtypes)
print('-'*50)

converted_data = np.array([tuple(r) for r in data], dtype = dtypes)

print(converted_data)
```

This gives the following output:

```
[[  1.00000000e+00   1.40000000e+00   5.00000000e+23]
 [  2.00000000e+00   2.30000000e+00   5.00000000e-12]
 [  3.00000000e+00   5.70000000e+00  -1.30000000e-02]]
--------------------------------------------------
[('col0', <class 'int'>), ('col1', <class 'float'>), ('col2', <class 'float'>)]
--------------------------------------------------
[(1,  1.4,   5.00000000e+23) (2,  2.3,   5.00000000e-12)
 (3,  5.7,  -1.30000000e-02)]
```

Tested on Python 3.5